# How to change behavior of Delete key in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I have a question about changing key behavior. I need to securely delete files on my PC but Windows doesn't support this. I installed Eraser, and it added entry to context menu. Is there some way to change behavior of any key on keyboard and assign some program/application to key?

Answer (score 1):

You could find out what command Eraser is calling (via system registry) then use `Autohotkey` to find the selected file then invoke the Eraser command when <kbd>Del</kbd> is pressed.

Edit: As ejmin points out be mindful that this change would apply to all uses of the <kbd>Del</kbd> key, potentially causing strange behaviour when editing text.

Comment: This could negatively change the behaviour of the delete button while editing text. Be careful and considerate while overwriting keys.